# Characteristic polynomial of differential of some function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be the four-dimensional real vector space $M_{2\times 2}$ of real $2\times$2 matrices. Show that by setting $$f(X)=X^2$$ for 2$\times$2 matrix $X$, we define a continously differentiable function $f :E\rightarrow E$. What is the characteristic polynomial of the linear map $Df(X): E\rightarrow E$ which is the derivative of $f$ ,at each $X\in E$ ? At what points $X\in E$ is $Df(X)$ an isomorphism?

I know that the function f is continously differentiable, and I also think $$Df(X)(H)=XH+HX,$$ but how can I find the characteristic polynomial of $Df(X)$ and the points where $Df(X)$ is an isomorphism? (This is my homework problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the derivative of $f$.

**Hint:** for a fixed $X$, find the matrix of the map $Df(X)(H)$ relative to the basis 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
In Kronecker product notation, you should end up with the matrix
$$
I \otimes X + X \otimes I
$$